# How would you create a nested list with recursion in Python?

Tags: python

For instance, if I want a list like: 
[2, 4, [5, 1]]

How would you implement a code that produces this with recursion?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? As I don't know, what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you desire the specific values to be generated. Are they random draws? Do they come from some other data source?

But once that part is described, you can make a recursive function like usual. For example, suppose you just want recursive copies of some range of values. Then you could do this:

```
def make_list(levels, num_elems):
    if levels > 0:
       return range(num_elems) + [make_list(levels-1, num_elems)]
    else:
       return range(num_elems)
```

For example:

```
In [3]: make_list(2, 2)
Out[3]: [0, 1, [0, 1, [0, 1]]]
```